# How to get Version Number of IE using Selenium JVM

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, selenium

Currently I am using the code below and I am getting the browser version name as internet explorer, and version number returns nothing. Please see my code below.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    caps.setCapability(
        InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
        true);
    String browsername = caps.getBrowserName(); // returning "internet explorer"
    String browserver = caps.getVersion(); // this part not returning any value
```

If this is not possible for IE, is there any way I can use Javascript in my Java Selenium project to get the version number? I would like get the version number for IE 7 and above versions.

Answer (score 1):

What you have tried is a plain one. You need to set a value to get a value. In your case, you have not set any value and so you get an empty value.

If you are looking to get the browser details during run time,

```
Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
String browserName = cap.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();
System.out.println(browserName);
String os = cap.getPlatform().toString();
System.out.println(os);
String v = cap.getVersion().toString();
System.out.println(v);
```

Comment: Purus, Thank you for your reply. When I am using RemoteWebDriver, how do I point to IEDriver?

Comment: This applies to all type of drivers.. Have you tried the code?